# Fastest way to sort very large files preferably with progress

Tags: multithreading, sorting, open-source, large-data, large-files

I have a 200GB flat file (one word per line) and I want to sort the file, then remove the duplicates and create one clean final TXT file out of it.

I tried `sort` with `--parallel` but it ran for 3 days and I got frustrated and killed the process as I didn't see any changes to the chunk of files it created in /tmp.

I need to see the progress somehow and make sure its not stuck and its working. Whats the best way to do so? Are there any Linux tools or open source project dedicated for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Linux, but if this is Gnu sort, you should be able to see the temporary files it creates from another window to monitor progress. The parallel feature only helps during the initial pass that sorts and creates the initial list of temporary files. After that, the default is a 16-way merge.

Say for example the first pass is creating temp files around 1GB in size. In this case, Gnu sort will end up creating 200 of these 1GB temp files before starting the merge phase. The 16 way merge means that 16 of those temp files will be merged at a time, creating temp files of size 16GB, and so on.

So one way to monitor progress is to monitor the creation of those temporary files.